# using findNavController.navigate(R.id.action) the status bar color changes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation

I have change the status bar color to white, but when i move from mainFragment to billing fragment using findNavController().navigate(R.id.action) then the status bar color changes to colorPrimary which is blue.
but when i use
FragmentUtils.getParent(this, MainTabUIDelegate::class.java)
?.setCurrentTab(BottomNavBar.TAB_Premium,"")
then color remains White.
**CAN ANYONE TELL ME WHY THE COLOR CHANGES TO colorPimary using findNavController().navigate(R.id.action) statement**

Comment: Where have you declared the statusBarColor ? in your layout file? or perhaps have you added a custom style?

Comment: the primary dark color is for status bar color according to my knowledge, i set colorPrimaryDark to white, which give me white status bar color, but while using findNavController.navigate the status bar color changes to window backgroundcolor